# Where did Maz Kanata's patrons go during the First Order's attack?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, first-order

When the first order attacked Maz Kanata's castle in *The Force Awakens*, what happened to all of the aliens and droids?

**Did they all suddenly flee, or were they casualties?**

In the movie, there seemed to be a lot of First Order ground troops for just picking up a couple people. Was there actually a fight with the castle's patrons?

We see that there are Resistance as well as First Order spies there, so **wouldn't it make sense to have a couple of soldiers or people capable of fighting present?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)), the bar's patrons appear to have been systematically slaughtered by the attacking stormtrooper forces

> *Swooping TIE fighters were methodically reducing the stone walls and
>   towers to dust, while others strafed smugglers and traders who were
>   frantically running for cover. **Their panicked flight was futile, as
>   they were quickly intercepted by squads of stormtroopers who had
>   landed nearby.***

The film's [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) is similarly downbeat

> Rey races through the trees -- sees Maz' castle -- BEING DESTROYED BY
>   FIRST ORDER SHIPS! Aliens RUNNING, GETTING OBLITERATED by SCREAMING
>   TIE FIGHTERS! Other TIE FIGHTERS and TRANSPORTERS LAND, STORMTROOPERS
>   in attack.

Comment: That explains why there were so many ground troops...

Comment: @JoshB. - Having a second "*stormtroopers round 'em up & kill 'em all*" scene would have been largely redundant. It's sufficient from a storytelling perspective to simply have the patrons disappear out of the picture when the next big event happens.

Comment: @Richard is this all the script says? I want to open a question about which patrons survived, but if this is all it says I won't bother.

Comment: @Hatandboots - The script is similarly unenlightening.

Comment: It would make more sense to see some First Order patrons fighting, as well as some Resistance fighters. It would have made the ground scene more interesting.

Comment: Did Maz survive?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Yes.