# Did Sidon Ithano and his crew survive the Battle of Takodana?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn, first-order

In *The Force Awakens*, Finn briefly joined the crew of the pirate Sidon Ithano, for a passage to the Outer Rim. While boarding *the Meson Martinet* nearby Maz Kanata's castle, Finn witnessed the destruction of the entire Hosnian System by the Starkiller Base and hurried back to Han Solo. Only a moment later the First Order launched an attack on Takodana, causing severe casualties. But were Ithano and his men able to take off before the battle took place and flee to the Outer Rim unharmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unknown, but I think Sidon did

So far, I don’t think there’s any canon information about what happened to Sidon Ithano or his crew when Maz Kanata’s castle got bombed. While the crew could well have died, I’m skeptical that Sidon Ithano would have been killed by a mere bombing run, given what he survived in *The Crimson Corsair and the Lost Treasure of Count Dooku*:

> Quiggold and the rest of the crew watched with sadness as the escape
> pod hurled them to safety. The cruiser was burning and sinking into
> the maelstrom of explosive sand.
>
> “Maybe…” offered Quiggold, “maybe he’s okay.”
>
> The crew all winced as the giant worm exploded through the hull of the
> ancient Separatist ship, screaming in a monstrous way that is best not
> described in detail.
>
> “Still…” Quiggold began in an optimistic tone.
>
> The entire ship exploded in a rage of fire and light.
>
> “Guess not,” said Quiggold, his voice heavy with regret.
>
> <sub>*The Crimson Corsair and the Lost Treasure of Count Dooku*</sub>

As Sidon himself says, “I don’t die so easily.”

Comment: Selected as the answer due to the positive assumption over Sidon's fate. Hopefully we'll see this cool-looking character again.

Answer (score 0):

### We don't know, but probably he's dead.

The fate of Sidon, his crew and his ship aren't described in any of the canon sources (The film, the novelisations, the factbooks) nor on the Databank entries for his ship and crew, nor in the script.

We do know that his ship was parked next to the castle and that [the castle (and its inhabitants) were leveled by incoming fire from TIE-Fighters.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120281/20774) It seems unlikely that they'd have missed such an obvious target.

Answer (score -1):

I Believe that although the Mason may have been destroyed it is highly unlikely that The Crimson Corsair would have been slain.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence to confirm this opinion?